# What attacks are possible if you can scrape a list of users?

Tags: attacks, user-management, user-enumeration

Have there been any attacks (or can you think of a potential attack) that hinged on being able to figure out if a user exists in a system?

For example, in a web app there is a "Reset password" page where you enter an email address (which acts as the login name, which in combination with a password, grants you access). If you enter an email that is not in the system, it will tell you the user does not exist. If you enter an email that *is* in the system, it will give you an "email sent" message.

This seems to me to be a case where the less you can reveal, the better, but I also can't really think of a way in which it would introduce a vulnerability but it is inconvenient to not give the user more info.

Comment: Well, you can always "attack" the registration form...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways this *could* be an issue:

- Considering some of the fallout of the Ashley Madison hack, being able to confirm whether or not a person has an account on a given site can be of value. In the case of this hack (per the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashley_Madison_data_breach)):

  > Following the hack, communities of internet vigilantes began combing through to find famous individuals, who they planned to publicly humiliate.
- On a similar note, attacks like [that on human rights activists](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2010/jan/14/china-human-rights-activists-cyber-attack), or even [watering hole attacks](https://krebsonsecurity.com/tag/watering-hole-attack/) can be better targeted if you are able to confirm (or not) that they have accounts.
- Phishing (and in specific, spear/whale phishing) can be made more effective if you can identify a good source to spoof. In that sense, if you can confirm a user has an account on a given site, then you are able to increase your chance of successful compromise ([tangentially related](https://www.apwg.org/resources/overview/avoid-phishing-scams)).

Possibly not what you had in mind, but I would also recommend you consider the methodology Brian Krebs uses in his investigations: he has been able to draw conclusive evidence about criminal hacking based on being able to tie people to online handles. This isn't an 'attack', but it can result in [DoS'ing individuals for some time](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2017/03/four-men-charged-with-hacking-500m-yahoo-accounts/).

I suspect the case most relevant to your question is being able to confirm whether a site is worth compromising in order to get to its users.

Notably, I suspect that considering that particular vector might lead to some specific design considerations, such as having your 'Reset Password' return a message akin to "Request received", as opposed to "Email sent".

Answer (score 3):

Sure, when someone is attacking the *user*, as opposed to the *system*. When an attacker is going after a person and knows their target's email address, they can enter the email address into dozens or hundreds of systems and see how each responds. This way they build up a list of interesting systems to attack to learn about the user. (As a bonus, none of the systems have any of their anti-hacking systems triggered, because there was only one login attempt for a specific user account.)

Answer (score 2):

Usually [username enumeration](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_User_Enumeration_and_Guessable_User_Account_(OWASP-AT-002)) is seen as a first step towards bruteforce or dictionary-based attacks; if you know a username is valid, then you know you aren't completely wasting your time trying to log into it.